# jQuery-ui dialog doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I've inherited a chrome extension that once you visit a page it spins through the DOM and adds a span which contains a list of 4 links when you mouse over the span the list displays the 4 links (anchors). I'd like when you click one of these 4 links if it could show a jQuery-ui dialog box with a button. The text of this box will be dynamic but I just need to get the dialog box showing on link click for now.

I'm not seeing any errors in my console but I'm also not seeing the dialog present itself. I do see the `console.log` being spit out from line 8 of `main.js` with the ruleDialog DIV showing.

Prior to me making adjustments these links worked normally (performed an API call) and they worked fine so I know the extension as a whole is functional (besides my dialog not showing).

I've done some looking around here on SO and I've found a few questions slightly related to my problem but have not had success with getting my particular case to work.

Here is a screenshot showing what it adds to the page:
[image: screenshot]

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "My Extension",
    "short_name": "ME",
    "author": "caleywoods",
    "description": "my extension",
    "version": "0.0.11",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
        //my pages
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
                "jquery-ui.min.js",
                "main.js"
            ],
            "css": [
                "style.css",
                "jquery-ui.min.css"
            ]
        }
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/*"
  ],

    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        //my pages (same as "matches")
    ]
}
```

**main.js**:

```
function addOurSpan() {
    var diaDiv   = document.createElement('DIV');

    diaDiv.id = "ruleDialog";
    diaDiv.innerHTML = "Testing!";
    diaDiv.style = "display: none;">

    console.log(diaDiv);

    $('.link .flat-list.buttons').each(function(i, e) {
        // Skip elements we've already added the dropdown to
        if ($(e).has('.my-class').length) { return; }

        // Create selected option/trigger div
        var selected = document.createElement('DIV');

        selected.className = 'dropdown lightdrop my-class';

        var selectedSpan = document.createElement('SPAN');
        selectedSpan.className = "selected";
        $(selectedSpan).text("OUR ADDED BUTTON");

        selected.appendChild(selectedSpan);

        // Create options div
        var options = document.createElement('DIV');
        options.className = 'drop-choices';

        // The rule by button label and hover-text
        var rules = {
            'Rule 1': 'Unrelated Stuff',
            'Rule 2': 'Miscellaneous Stuff',
            'Rule 3': 'Repetitive Stuff',
            'Rule 4': 'Scam Stuff',
        };

        for (var r in rules) {
            var ruleLink = document.createElement('A');

            $(ruleLink).text(r);
            ruleLink.title = rules[r];
            ruleLink.className = 'choice';

            $(ruleLink).click(function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                // $("#ruleDialog").dialog({
                //     modal:true,
                //     buttons: {
                //         Accept: function() {
                //             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                //         }
                //     }
                // });
                $("#ruleDialog").dialog();
            });
        }
        var li = document.createElement('LI');
        var spacer = document.createElement('DIV');
        spacer.className = "spacer";

        spacer.appendChild(selected);
        spacer.appendChild(options);
        li.appendChild(spacer);
        e.appendChild(li);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() { addOurSpan(); });
```

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added a breakpoint and stepped through, it steps through each rule and creates the anchor, sets the title, and classname. Once it reaches the $ruleLink.click binding it skips on down to add the anchor to the list inside the span.

I reverted my changes back to the way things where when they're just plain links that make API calls and the behavior is the exact same but clicking the link will fire the click event bound and make the API call. 

I've also verified that jQuery UI is loading by doing a console.log($.ui) inside the click event and it logs the version

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, maybe someone else will.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for taking a look. One interesting thing is that if you visit the "index.html" example page included with your default jQuery UI download from "inside" the extension (by visiting chrome-extension://extensionId/index.html) their dialog example will not open when you click the button but nothing else really works in that example either because I believe `manifest_version: 2` executes some content restrictions about executing inline javascript, this is what forces us to write our code in other scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have fixed this. I was creating diaDiv and setting the ID to "ruleDialog" but I needed to actually append it to the body of the page. I found a div named "content" and called $("#content").append(diaDiv). After doing that and cleaning up my click event binding code it works great.